# XFCE how to show pop up when using sound function keys

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, audio-volume

On Unity and Ubuntu, I noticed that if I change the volume via function keys, it shows a pop up. Can I have the same ability with Arch and Xfce? It already does it with brightness (if I press the brightness key, it pops up an indicator.)

Note: I mean the pop up indicator. The volume does change when I use the function keys, its just that it doesn't tell me it does.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the package `xfce4-notifyd`. You'll need to configure it with `xfce4-notifyd-config` as it says in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications#Standalone).

Comment: clarified question